# want to read more than 50,000 txt files and save them in linked list in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
class linklist     //linked list class
{
    struct main_node;
    struct sub_node;

    struct main_node   // main node that only have head pointers in it
    {
        sub_node *head;
        main_node()
        {   head=NULL;  }
    };
    main_node array[26];
    struct sub_node
    {
        double frequency;
        string word;
        sub_node *next;
        sub_node()
        {   frequency=1;    word="";    next=NULL;  }
    };

public:
    void add_node(string phrase)
    {
        char alphabat1=phrase[0];
        if(isupper(alphabat1))
        {
            alphabat1=tolower(alphabat1);
        }
        if(!isalpha(alphabat1))
            return;

        sub_node*temp = new sub_node;
        temp->word = phrase;

        sub_node*current = array[alphabat1-97].head;

        if(current == NULL)
        array[alphabat1-97].head = temp;

        else
        {
            while(current -> next != NULL && phrase != current-> word)
            {   current= current->next; }

            if(current->word == phrase)
                current->frequency++;
            else
                current->next  = temp; //adding words to linklist
        }
    }

    void display()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
        {
        sub_node *temp=array[i].head;
        cout<<char(i+97)<<" -> ";
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<temp->word<<" ("<<temp->frequency<<")  ";
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
void parsing_documents(char *path)
{
    char token[100];
    ifstream read;
    read.open(path);
    do
    {
        read>>token;    // parsing words
        add_node(token);    //sending words to linked list

    }
    while(!read.eof());
        read.clear();
        read.close();
}
void reading_directory()
{
 // code to read multiple files

   HANDLE          hFile;                // Handle to file
   WIN32_FIND_DATA FileInformation;      // File information
   char tempPattern[90];
   strcpy(tempPattern,"*.txt");
   hFile = ::FindFirstFile(tempPattern, &FileInformation);
   long count=0;
   if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
        do
        {
            count++;
            cout<<"."<<count;
            this->parsing_documents( FileInformation.cFileName);
        }
        while(TRUE == ::FindNextFile(hFile, &FileInformation));
   } 
    ::FindClose(hFile);

}
};
void main()
{
    linklist member;
    member.reading_directory();
    member.display();
}
```

I am working on a project in which I have to read more than 50,000 text files parse  their words and save them in a linked list in a sorted manner , i have made the code in C++. it's working quite efficiently but I have one problem in this regard that it is not reading the  files correctly sometimes 3000 sometimes 4000. I have searched for it a lot but i couldn't succeed to find my fault . . here is my code in C++ 
    if any body help me in this regard i would be very thankful

Comment: It would be a good idea to check the result of new(). If you're using a nothrow version, make sure it's not zero. If it throws you might want to catch the error.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong?  Does it give an error message, or an unhandled exception, or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!read.eof()` only checks for end of file, not errors reading the file, such as a networked mounted file system not being ready, disk error, or lack of permission to read the file.  You should check for all failures, with `while(read)` which has an overloaded operator to check everything for you.  So, if the file fails, you stop trying to read from it.  You should also check the status *before* trying to read from the file.  As such, `while(read) { ... }` is preferable to the do/while loop.  After the loop, you might issue a warning or error to the user of you did not reach the end of file `!read.eof()` so they can investigate that specific file.

Try to avoid `char *` and `char []` as much possible as this is highly error prone.  You have a char[100].  What happens if the string is longer than 100 characters?  `read >> token` may overwrite the stack -- such as to damage the `ifstream read`.

Consider using `std::list<sub_node>` to avoid having to re-invent and re-debug the wheel?  You would no longer need the next pointer as std::list already does that for you.  This would leave far less code to debug.

Comment: sorry didn't get your point @jonathan , kindly if you explain